# Select the matching/sum up total in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all the id's that matches/sum up my total qty.

Example if my total qty is 40 then my query will stops until it sums up all the qty at exactly or greater than 40.

See screenshots

[image]

Comment: Consider using row_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sql server 2012 and above, you can use this script.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT PK_TRXNO, FK_iwItems, qty, 
        total = SUM(qty) OVER( PARTITION BY FK_iwItems ORDER BY PK_TRXNO DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) 
    FROM @MyTable
)
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN total > 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY PK_TRXNO DESC)  
    FROM CTE 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE2
WHERE total <= 40 OR ( total> 40 AND RN = 1)
```

Comment: Hi Sir Thanks for the quick answer I really appreciate it, however i still finding a way to tweak your query, and make it stop once it reach the 40, it is still not stopping supposedly rows 6 (once it reach 40 or greater than)

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you very much Sir!